# I can't create a page with render() with Symfnony 5

Tags: twig, symfony5

I'm new with Symfony and I'm just trying to create my first page. I'm obviously following the official Symfony tutorial [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) and I did everything step by step. However, I can't load the file .

Here's LuckyController.php :

```
    <?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class LuckyController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
      * @Route("/lucky/number")
      */

    public function number()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', [
            'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
}
```

routes.yaml :

```
# the "app_lucky_number" route name is not important yet
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

number.html.twig :

```
{# templates/lucky/number.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Your lucky number is {{ number }}</h1>


{% endblock %}
```

[and here's where the file is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFEIw.png) and all the [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tiVq.png).

I did everything right but still don't understand why it doesn't work. I even emptied the cache. 
Can I get some help please? thankkkks

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshot your line 20 of LuckyController.php has:

```
number.html.twig
```

However, in your code snippet as part of your question you have:

```
lucky/number.html.twig
```

Ensure that your file is really inside the `lucky` folder and ensure that your path is correctly set to `lucky/number.html.twig`.